# Who is this 1980s character?

Tags: cartoon, character-identification

Who is this character. It’s not Emmet Brown from Back to the Future but an 80s cartoon / film character?

[image: Close-up of a mural. A bald man with white beard, red-framed sunglasses, and a drop of blood from his nose. The BTTF logo is above, and a Ninja Turtle below.]

Comment: What made you assume it was an 80s character?

Comment: What's the source of this image?

Comment: @Laurel It looks like a picture of a street art

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That looks like [Master Roshi](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Master_Roshi) from the *Dragon Ball* franchise. The *Dragon Ball* manga was released in 1984, and the anime in 1986, which would make it possible for him to show up among "80s characters", although if this mural is from outside Japan, he might be much more obscure, given it took time for the works to get translated.

[image: Image of Master Roshi]

[image: Better match, provided by OrangeDog, complete with orange shirt and nosebleed]

Comment: Is there a significance to the nosebleed that's in the OP and in one of the images of the answer?

Comment: @shoover: [It's an anime trope that people who are suddenly aroused will get a nosebleed](https://www.cbr.com/anime-aroused-nosebleed-origin-science/) and Master Roshi is a lecher with beautiful women around him. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2KHUBwcBB0

Comment: Thanks, I'm not into anime so wasn't aware of the trope.

Comment: He’s also known as the Turtle Hermit, and there’s a turtle in the bottom left…

Comment: @jmoreno That turtle's mask probably indicates it is Michelangelo of the TMNT.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: I think it's actually not specifically an anime trope as such, but rather a bit of "superstition"/"urban myth" in at least some East Asian cultures. I have repeatedly heard Chinese people make a reference to getting a nosebleed when seeing a beautiful woman, as if there were a commonly known causal relationship between the two, and they explained it to me along the lines of "people say", as if it were a commonly known folk wisdom rather than anything related to anime in particular.

Comment: @shoover Generally speaking, I think "perverted nosebleed" is a trope which is more common in Eastern culture. I remember watching a Chinese movie where such a thing was depicted, and some Western drawings also started taking inspiration too. Edit: I just realised the previous comment mentioned it.